# Django + mod_wsgi + apache + wamp optimization technique for windows

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, wampserver

I am trying to host my Django App to Wamp in Windows 7. I already configured mod_wsgi correctly and had run a test project to verify it.

However, the server is really taking time to load as I migrated my dev project. I have read articles about optimizing mod_wsgi performance by enabling mod_wsgi daemon mode on non-Windows platforms.

My questions is: Is there a way to optimize mod_wsgi performance in Windows platform?

Side note: Its already 30 minutes since I have tried to access my django project and the page is still loading. There is no error log generated in Apache error log and the Wamp server is still running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it hangs indefinitely it is probably this issue:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api

This can be caused by certain third party Python modules which have C extensions, which have not been implemented properly so they work in Python sub interpreters.

Presuming your are only hosting the one WSGI application, add:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Comment: This solution worked, though in windows, we have to include double quote . It should be: `WSGIApplicationGroup "%{GLOBAL}"`. Thanks sir and more power!

Comment: I know of no reasons why you need double quotes. Never had to previously. On Windows you sometimes get problems when editing Apache configs due to editors which are too smart doing stupid things with smart quotes, or pasting in other strange Unicode characters. Maybe there was some strange character in there which wasn't visible and editing it got rid of it.

Comment: I haven't copy pasted the code from the internet sir. I have manually typed it. In my case, all arguments/values in wamp(http.conf)+windows must be enclosed with quotation mark or else, the apache won't start